# Timer kills task/job if it runs longer than timer interval

Tags: c#, .net, timer, threadpool, c#-2.0

I would to make a timer which behaviour is like this:

- if processing time of task/job is less than timer interval, start timer in (timer.interval - processing time job/job)
- if processing time of job/task is more than timer interval, start next job/task immediatly

Code below works but I would like to know why in the ElapsedEventHandler method job/task must be first done and then we can set new timer interval. Elapsed event of System.Timers.Timer is raised when interval has elapsed. With the option AutoReset = false we set that the Timer raises the Elapsed event only once, after the first Interval has elapsed. We have to then manually call Timer.Start() to start it again.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

 namespace TestTimer
 {
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer t;
        private static double intervalMiliseconds;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            intervalMiliseconds = 5000; // 5 seconds

            t           = new Timer();
            t.Interval  = intervalMiliseconds;
            t.AutoReset = false;
            t.Elapsed  += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            t.Start();

            log("Timer started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            log("Interval is: " + defaultIntervalMiliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void log(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text + "\n");
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // if t.Interval is set here thread just kills the job if it
            // runs longer than interval
            t.Interval = intervalMiliseconds;
            log("ElapsedEvent triggered at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            // job
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            log("job started" );
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000); // 8 sec
            log("job ended" );
            TimeSpan jobTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
            log("job took " + jobTime.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

            // if we set t.Interval here it works so first the job
            // must be done and than we can set timer interval ? why ?
            //t.Interval = intervalMiliseconds;

            if (jobTime.TotalMilliseconds < t.Interval)
            {
                t.Interval = t.Interval - jobTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                log("Job ended Earlier starting Event in: " + t.Interval);
            }
            else
            {
                t.Interval = 100;
                log("Job overpass interval. Current time: " +
                     DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

            t.AutoReset = false;
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Result of this:

[image]

If we comment t.Interval at the start of method OnTimedEvent and uncomment t.Interval after the job has done everything works. Result of this:

[image]

Why we can not set timer interval at the start of method OnTimedEvent. If we do if the task/job runs longer than the timer interval, thread just kills the job. I would really appreciate if anyone has some ideas? Does this have to do with synhronization of thread with main thread (which timer runs)? When we call method OnTimedEvent the timer will not call that method again because it has AutoReset = false, what difference does it make where we set timer properties?

Comment: I haven't read though your whole question, but why not just start the timer at the _start_ of the job. When the job completes, if the timer has elapsed, start another job, otherwise wait for the timer to elapse.

Answer (score 4):

```
   t.Interval = intervalMiliseconds;
```

That's indeed the troublemaker.  It is pretty unintuitive behavior, one that the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) for Timer.Interval specifically warns about in a Note:

> If Enabled and AutoReset are both set to false, and the timer has previously been enabled, setting the Interval property causes the Elapsed event to be raised once, as if the Enabled property had been set to true. To set the interval without raising the event, you can temporarily set the AutoReset property to true.

It's a fairly silly hack but does work.  Just delaying assigning the value is certainly the better way to do it.  Doing it early doesn't buy you anything, other than trouble, the timer isn't going tick anyway since you've got AutoReset = false.

System.Threading.Timer is the better timer class with many fewer quirks.  It for one doesn't swallow exceptions without any diagnostic in the callback method.  Which your code is quite sensitive to, the timer will just stop ticking since the exception bypasses the t.Start() call and you'll have no idea why.  Strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**!! No and never Timer kill task/job if it runs longer than timer interval !!**

if processing time of task/job is less than timer interval,
after timer interval/span.
if processing time of job/task is more than timer interval,
start next job/task after  timer interval/span into a new Thread.

**so for minimizing idle time you should keep timer interval small.**
 In System.Timers.Timer class internally already Threading Implemented. so don`t need to implements threading.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, firstly thank you for taking the time to answer. Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here, read [answer] to create helpful answers and add to the community.